# Как подписать сообщение по стандарту PKCS#7?

Tags: php, linux, openssl

Задача: сформировать подписанное по стандарту *PKCS#7* сообщение из файла.

Пытаюсь сделать с помощью функции *PHP*:

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(
        $infile,
        $outfile,
        $this->_getCertPath(),
        [$this->_getPrivateKeyPath(), self::CERT_PASSWORD],
        [],
        PKCS7_NOCHAIN|PKCS7_NOCERTS
    );
```

Выдает ошибку:

> error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

При этом через консоль все работает:

```
 echo "999" | openssl smime -sign -signer certificate.cer -inkey private.key  -nochain -nocerts -outform PEM -nodetach
```

Понятно, что можно сделать через `proc_open()`, но хочется этого избежать. 
И хочется понять в чем же дело.

Права на сертификат и ключ: 777.

Ось: GNU/Linux

Comment: *no start line* — а что у вас в первой строке файла, путь к которому который вы передаёте третьим параметром? (приведите вывод `hexdump -C этот.файл | head`) кстати, уточните, и как выглядит содержимое этого третьего параметра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

такая ошибка сведетельствует, скорее всего, о том, что в файле, который указан функции в качестве содержащего сертификат, первая строка не соответствует ожидаемому:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

т.е., видимо, либо файл «не тот», либо `$this->_getCertPath()` возвращает «не то».

---

я протестировал так:

1. создал файл с сообщением:

   ```
   $ echo '12345' > msg.txt
   ```
2. сгенерировал сертификат и ключ, введя для файла с ключом пароль `1234`:

   ```
   $ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 30
   ...
   ```
3. вызвал функцию (основываясь на примере из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php)):

   ```
   $ php -r 'if (openssl_pkcs7_sign("msg.txt", "signed.txt", "file://cert.pem", \
   array("file://key.pem", "1234"), [], PKCS7_NOCHAIN|PKCS7_NOCERTS)) \
   { echo "ok\n"; }'
   ```

   и она успешно выполнилась, вернув ожидаемый `ok` и сохранив подписанное сообщение в файл `signed.txt` (строки с *mime*-кодированной подписью заменены на `...` для краткости):

   ```
   MIME-Version: 1.0
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
   Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name="smime.p7m"
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

   MIICkwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIChDCCAoACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMBYGCSqGSIb3
   ...
   ```

   **важно:** строки с путями к файлам с ключом и с сертификатом должны начинаться с `file://` — иначе я получал ошибки («не найден ключ»: `error getting private key`, «не найден сертификат»: `error getting cert`).